# print only one single empty line

Tags: python, printf

I am reading files in a folder in a python. I want print the each file content separate by a single empty line.

So, after the for loop I am adding `print("\n")` which adding two empty lines of each file content. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: God this people is fast!

Comment: @dimo414 May I know why did you rollback?

Comment: @KevinGuan you deleted "How can I resolve this problem" which is the question.  Without that the post is just a series of statements.

Comment: @dimo414 I think that people don't need add something like that because everyone know that his asking a question. I'll remember this next time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
print()
```

will print a single new line in Python 3 (no parens needed in Python 2).

The docs for [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) describe this behavior (notice the `end` parameter), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/113632) discusses disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Because `print` automatically adds a new line, you don't have to do that manually, just call it with an empty string:

```
print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

From `help(print)` (I think you're using Python 3):

> print(`value`, ..., `sep=' '`, `end='\n'`, `file=sys.stdout`, `flush=False`)
>
> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
>      Optional keyword arguments:
>
> file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
>      sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
>      end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
>      flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.

So `print()`'s default `end` argument is `\n`. That means you don't need add a `\n` like `print('\n')`. This will print two newlines, just use `print()`.

By the way, if you're using Python 2,  use `print`.

Answer (score 0):

`print` has a `\n` embedded in it....so you don't need to add `\n` by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to be really explicit, use

```
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Write method doesn't append line break by default. It's probably a bit more intuitive than an empty print.